# Change the color of div when user clicks over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few div and when a user clicks on any one of them i wish to change its background color, and i also want that for the first time by default the first div should be active with the colored background

Code that i am using is

```css
.tabs.active a {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 tabs">
  <a href="#">
    <p>First</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs">
  <a href="#">
    <p>Second</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs">
  <a href="#">
    <p>Third</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

but the color is not changing. can anyone please tell me where the code has gone wrong

Comment: `.active` is a class. You cannot toggle a class with CSS...only Javscript

Comment: Do you want to change the background of the div or of the anchor?

Comment: Are you using any javascript to assign `.active` class in tabs?

Comment: @Dustin Poissant i wish to change the background of div

Comment: @Anuj Kumar no i havn't

Comment: @Paulie_D can u plz tell the proper way to achieve the result

Comment: @jazz Only buttons and links can use `:active` so you will have to use JavaScript

Comment: @jazz That means the tab is not being assigned with `.active` class after clicking because of this your css is not working. Try a line of jquery to assign the class. It will work for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `:focus` Pseudo class with `Tabindex`.

But if you focus any other things, then the background style of tabs will be lost :(

```css
.tabs>a>p:focus{ 
  background-color:gray !important;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs" >
    <a href="#">
        <p tabindex="1"> First </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs" >
    <a href="#">
        <p tabindex="2"> Second </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs" >
    <a href="#">
        <p tabindex="3"> Third </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

It is not directly possible to catch a click event with CSS, but there does exist a couple of "hacks". One of them is to use a checkbox:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: 4px solid green;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: table;
  margin: 20px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label div {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
<label for="cb1">
  <div>
    Div 1 - click me
  </div>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
<label for="cb2">
  <div>
    Div 2 - click me
  </div>
</label>
```

As you see the divs are encased in labels which are bound to hidden checkboxes. When you click the label (or anything inside it) the checkbox state changes, and CSS is applied thus.

The selector `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label div` finds any checked checkbox, finds the direct sibling of type `label` and the `div` within. It is therefore required that the label comes directly after its companion checkbox in the html.

You should be able to modify this code to suit your needs.

**UPDATE:** In my previous version the label (and therefore the click registration bounds) extended to the left and right edges of the parent container (the body, in this case). By setting `display: table;` on the label one avoids this while keeping the block behaviour. You can also use `inline-block` if you want the divs on the same line.

Comment: I like this creative answer, hypothetically if they wanted only one "active" at a time could they use radios?

Comment: @Dustin-Poissant Yes, but you have to remember to give the radio buttons a common name.

Comment: This code uses invalid HTML. `<div>` elements **CANNOT** be inside `<label>`s.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel `div`-elements are not supposed to go inside inline elements, such as `label`; that is correct. However, you can change the `label` to a block level element in css. Also, no modern browser would really care that it's not strictly valid.

Comment: @MagnusBuvarp If you are in a corporate environment, if you require XHTML or if you just plain and simply care about the HTML validation results, you **DO NOT** want to do this.

Comment: Also, check https://jsfiddle.net/gz7t3bt4/ for a **valid** HTML version.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I see what you mean, but in your example if you want the background-color to cover the full height of the div you'd still have to make  the span a block-level element, which in practice would be the same as using a div. Alternatively you could play around with line-height, but that's not very dynamic.

Comment: @MagnusBuvarp My argument to is is that the HTML will be valid. Also, setting a `<span>` to be a block-element (which is what I did) is a better option than purelly incorrect HTML that just happens to behave the way you expect.

Answer (score 4):

With **:target** pseudo-class

```css
.col-md-2:target {background-color: black;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 tabs" id="first">
    <a href="#first">
        <p> First </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs" id="second" >
    <a href="#second">
        <p> Second </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs" id="third">
    <a href="#third">
        <p> Third </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".tabs").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".tabs.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});//

$(".tabs").eq(0).trigger("click");
```

```css
.tabs.active a
{
  display: block;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs">
    <a href="#">
        <p> First </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs">
    <a href="#">
        <p> Second </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs">
    <a href="#">
        <p> Third </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$(".tabs").click(function(){
$(".active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

It will assign `.active` class to your clicked element and your CSS will be applied.

Comment: Previously they question said "Using only CSS", and so this answer would be incorrect. But now they have edited the question to allow for the possibility of JavaScript. So your answer is now correct. I would just add to your answer that this requires jQuery. And I would wrap the entire thing in a `$(function(){/* code here */})`

Comment: There is no need of using jQuery here, especially if ES6 is available.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#menu ul li a').click(function (ev) {
    $('#menu ul li').removeClass('selected');
    $(ev.currentTarget).parent('li').addClass('selected');
});
```

});

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/LrMsA/)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is wrong if I understood you correctlly. Here is my proposed sollution:

```
.tabs:active
{
background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: let me be more specific. You SHOULD not use it on anything but buttons and links because that is all IE supports, even the latest version.

Comment: @Dustin is right - this does not work in IE, however it works in Microsoft Edge

Comment: @Tezekiel Did you click on the "Known Issues Tab" maybe you should. being supported but with major bugs is not really being supported.

Comment: Of course I did. I agree it doesn't work up to IE 11. But also, I am saying, that only 2% of users use those browsers.

Comment: Down vote for not saying this is the solution for 98% of cases? Really?

Comment: I wouldn't say all versions of IE make up 2% of users. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) shows nearly 6% and it is known for being biased against IE since it counts the mostly tech savvy visitors to it's site. Plus even if it did work you should not use unsupported features, it is not guaranteed to work the way you expect it and even if it does it is not guaranteed to keep working that way in future versions.

Comment: I personally always make fallback sollutions but I presumed that this was the sollution that OP wanted.

Comment: No that 98% includes IE that officially claims that it does support it while it actually doesn't. A lot more than 2% of people use IE. The latest stats say 6%. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: Yes, but IE 11+ do support it. W3schools shows all IE in one number.

Comment: Accordion to "Can I Use" IE supports it, but if you read the "known issues" it really doesn't support it, even IE11+ DOES NOT SUPPORT IT.

Comment: Have you actually opened IE11 and gone to your fiddle and tried it? It does not work.

Comment: I saw that it doesn't work for :hover, didn't check it, until now that is. You win :) At least it works on Edge :)

Comment: So "At least it works on Edge" basically means we can start using it in about 5 years. It will take at least that long to phase out enough of IE that we can stop worrying about IE. As long as IEs usage is >1% I can not use it at work. For personal projects that are target at people who are more tech savy I do not worry about IE, but for a professional product target at the general public you must support IE.

Comment: Of course. I am not employed in the industry so I don't know that kind of stuff. Thank you for educating me.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear from your question whether you wanted each of the divs to change colors independently or whether you wanted only one of the div's to be highlighted.

If you only want one of the divs to be selected at a time use you can use @Magnus Buvarp solution but instead of using checkboxes use radio buttons that share the same name.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
input[type="radio"] { /* changed to "radio" */
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label { /* changed to "radio" */
  display: table;
  margin: 20px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label div { /* changed to "radio" */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<strong>There can be only one!</strong>

<!-- changed to "radio" and added "name" attribute -->
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="rb1">
<label for="rb1">
  <div>
    Click Me!
  </div>
</label>

<!-- changed to "radio" and added "name" attribute -->
<!-- notice the same for both radio buttons is the same -->
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="rb2">
<label for="rb2">
  <div>
    No! Click Me!
  </div>
</label>
```

You can see now that when you click on one of them the other becomes unselected.

The trade off here is that once you select one, one of the two always has to be selected. Whether this is the right way to go depends on your needs.

P.S. Tweaked the colors a little bit, don't ask me why, I don't know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** property in **jQuery** or **JavaScript** (**[`element.classList.toggle("active")`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-toggle-an-element-class-in-javascript/)**)

```
$(".tabs a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent(".tabs").toggleClass("active")
});
```

then changes in CSS:

```
.tabs.active{
  background: black;
}
```

```js
$(".tabs a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent(".tabs").toggleClass("active")
});
```

```css
.tabs.active{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs active">
  <a href="#">
    <p>First</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs">
  <a href="#">
    <p>Second</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 tabs">
  <a href="#">
    <p>Third</p>
  </a>
</div>
```